# How can I retain initalizer list of POD structs after adding a common ancestor?

Tags: c++

I have inherited some code which uses a series of POD structs, and would like to give them all a common base class, so that I can store them in a common system.

I should mention that these structs are used as interop classes to C#, so I need to retain their POD and aggregate qualities.

So pretty simple, e.g. previously

```
struct A {
   char *id;
   float *matrix;
}
struct B {
   char *id;
   int some_property;
}
```

There are currently frequent uses of initaliser lists throughout the code:

```
B myB{ otherthing.id, otherthing.property };
```

and I want to make them all a `Base`:

```
struct Base {
};

struct A : public Base {
   char *id;
   float *matrix;
}
struct B : public Base {
   char *id;
   int some_property;
}
```

which is now breaking the initializer list behaviour. Is there a way I can retain the current initalisation code?

Comment: The easiest solution probably would be to upgrade to C++17, which allows aggregates with base classes. If not, I suppose you could make it work with C++14 by adding both a default constructor and a constructor with parameters for initialization. Or the same in C++11 if `Base` is empty as in the example you show. But I don't feel competent enough to answer this question, sorry.

Comment: I'm using C++17, but the initalizer list example above won't compile, as it is trying to cast a `char*` to a `Base`.

Comment: Hmm, peculiar. It seems that you need `B myB{ {}, otherthing.id, otherthing.property };` to initialize `Base` (or at least GCC happily accepts it in this form). So I guess you need those constructors to make it work without changing initializations. The classes won't be aggregates, but still POD. https://wandbox.org/permlink/IWLTACHv7x25FAZx